# I used Adapter class to inflate the RecyclerView-Mainactivity. How can I navigate from X-Activity(navigated from adapter class) to MainActivity

Tags: android-intent, android-recyclerview

I used an Adapter class to inflate the `RecyclerView` which is in `MainActivity`. When I click on the sub-item of the `RecyclerView` it navigated to `SomeOtherActivity`. Now I want to navigate back to `MainActivity` and change the sub-item (`RecyclerAdapter`). How can I access the `RecyclerAdapter` class? How can I access the list item using `MyViewHolder`?

Answer (score 0):

Not getting your question. By default back press will lead to your desired activity. If not then override onBackPressed() method of [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class. If not solved then elaborate more.